# Generalize Include Path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, include-path

I am using Microsoft Visual Studios 2010, and I have found out how to set new include paths. Now I want to make it so that other users can utilize my project. If my current path is C:\Users\jsestrad\Documents\Homework\EE350\Lab\power, for example, is there a way I can start making it search from ..\Homework\EE350\Lab\power so that other users can utilize the include path?

Comment: Schools don't tend to talk much about source control or the ways a team of programmers work on a project with main and release branches.  But in Real Life, that matters a great deal and affects a proper answer to your question.  Talk to your teacher about this.

Comment: @Hans Passant Actually this is for a work project. I am the first one to start working with Visual Studios at my work, so there are a few things I am tasked with figuring out. I just used the path as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MSBuild properties in the path, including `$(ProjectDir)`, which is the directory in which the project is located, and `$(SolutionDir)`, which is the directory in which the solution is located.

The simplest thing to do would be to ensure that everyone has the include files in the same location relative to the project, then set the include path relative to `$(ProjectDir)`.

For example, if your project is in **C:\Users\jsestrad\Documents\Homework\EE350\Lab** and your includes are in **C:\Users\jsestrad\Documents\Homework\Stuff**, you could add **$(ProjectDir)..\Stuff** to your include path.

Comment: What is the value of $(ProjectDir)? This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, but my main concern is that if I share this project with another user, the fact that my username will, of course, be different from another user, it will not work.

Comment: It is the directory in which the .vcxproj project file is located.  If you move the project to a new location and open the project file from that new location, the $(ProjectDir) property will be "updated" to the new location (there's not really any "update" required:  the value is computed on the fly by the build system.

Comment: Awesome! I found the macro where $(ProjectDir) was defined, and I saw that it would not be an issue. Thanks a ton. It was exactly what I needed!